# How to add elements to initalizer list using cin

Tags: list, cin

I've started learning how to use initializer lists in functions. It seems that a good way to pass arguments to a function that uses an initializer list parameter is to pass an already made initializer list into the function, although I might be wrong, it just seems like a good idea. I am wondering if there is any way to add elements to an initializer list through values passed by cin like you would in a vector. When any amount of values is entered and added to the list the already created list would be passed into the function once the user indicates they are finished entering values?

Comment: Initializer lists are a *convenience feature* and cannot be modified after creation.  If you don't know the elements beforehand, just append them to a `vector` instead.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Didn't you say you already know how to work with a `vector`?  Also, it would be bad design for a function to accept *exclusively* initializer lists.

Comment: I can work with vectors but the same rules dont always apply to IL's? would it allow me to copy the contents of a vector into an IL that way?

Comment: There are very limited ways to construct an initializer list: you can only do so using the literal `{ a, b, c, ... }` syntax.  As I said, a function that accepts an initializer list is purely for the sake of *syntactic convenience*.